# Как столбец с типом Timestamp преобразовать в дату?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Есть датасет, в котором признак - это дата в формате timestamp:

```
Out[9]:
    userjd  timestamp
197    313  1491144981
319     20  1491180276
183    468  1491138897
453    427  1491208997
323     72  1491181163
```

Хочу преобразовать в дату.

Пробую так:

```
train_full['timestamp'] = pd.Timestamp.to_datetime(train_full['timestamp'])
```

Получаю ошибку:

> AttributeError: type object 'Timestamp' has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Хотя в документации Pandas [есть такое](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_pydatetime.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы преобразовать UNIX epoch / timestamp в `datetime64`:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], unit="s")
```

---

результат:

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]:
   user_id   timestamp                date
0      313  1491144981 2017-04-02 14:56:21
1       20  1491180276 2017-04-03 00:44:36
```

Comment: Так не работает. Все равно в 1970-01-01 создает. Может потому что изначально timestamp уже datetime64[ns]? в df.info()

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, можете сохранить часть вашего фрейма в виде parquet или pickle файла и выложить его куда-нибудь?

Comment: Без проблем - https://fex.net/ru/s/bpod5sm

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, я не просто так попросил сохранить фрейм в __бинарном__ формате ;) Теперь мне понадобится точный код при помощи которого вы парсили жтот файл, чтобы воспроизвести проблему. Если бы был бинарный файл, то было бы достаточно просто прочитать его...

Comment: train = pd.read_csv('input/train_2.csv')

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, и вы утверждаете, что после этого `timestamp` - будет иметь тип данных `datetime64[ns]`? Не верю! (c) Станиславский) PS в общем, ждем __воспроизводимый__ пример данных

Comment: https://fex.net/ru/s/1yp1dsx

Answer (score 0):

У вас по ссылке же функция называется `to_pydatetime`, а не `to_datetime`

Comment: Да, точно. Изменил на такое 
train_full['timestamp'] = pd.Timestamp.to_pydatetime(train_full['timestamp']) и все равно ошибка TypeError: descriptor 'to_pydatetime' requires a 'pandas._libs.tslibs.c_timestamp._Timestamp' object but received a 'Series'

Comment: Ну а когда я просто делаю train_full['created'] = train_full['timestamp'].dt.to_pydatetime(), то он создает новую колонку и пишет там 1970-01-01 для всех записей одинаково, без привязки к timestamp

Comment: А без .dt. если попробовать?

Comment: И вообще какого точно типа колонка эта? .info() от датафрейма что говорит?

Comment: Без .dt AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'

Comment: timestamp  8674 non-null   datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 0):

Все. Разобрался.

Изначально еще раз загрузил df. В нем дата, которая внешне была в timestamp, хранилась в виде int64.

Применил df['created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],unit='s')

Создалась колонка и значение для 1491207064 - 2017-04-03 08:11:04 (то есть корректно). Тип данных при этом datetime64[ns].

Comment: и чем же это решение отличается от того, что я вам дал раньше? ;)

Comment: @MaxU Понятно чем, свое всегда лучше :-)